# SUM and JOIN to display in one record

Tags: sql-server, join, sum

I have three tables: Table1 (AF), Table2 (MC) and Table3 (SC)

I currently have a Query for these tables as such:

```
SELECT
AF.[Product Number],
AF.[Week End Date],
AF.[Inv Change Cost],
AF.[Gross Sales Lbs],
AF.[Production Lbs],
MC.[Actual Usage Cost] AS MeatCost,
SC.[Actual Usage Cost] AS SeasonCost
FROM Table1 AF
FULL JOIN Table2 MC ON MC.[Product Number] = AF.[Product Number] AND MC.[Week Ending Date] = AF.[Week End Date]
FULL JOIN Table3 SC ON SC.[Product Number] = AF.[Product Number] AND SC.[Week Ending Date] = MC.[Week Ending Date]
WHERE
AF.[Product Number] = '96443' AND
AF.[Week End Date] = '2/4/2017' AND
MC.[Rout Line Name] = 'Total Cost' AND
SC.[Rout Line Name] = 'Total Cost'
```

Which Returns the following:

```
Prod # | WE Date | IC Cost | Gross Sales | Prod Lbs | Meat Cost | Season Cost |
96443    2/4/2017  -123456   1000           2000       5000        10000
96443    2/4/2017  -123456   1000           2000       5000        20000
96443    2/4/2017  -123456   1000           2000       6000        10000
96443    2/4/2017  -123456   1000           2000       6000        20000
```

However, I want to be able to SUM Meat and Season so the table would look like this:

```
Prod # | WE Date | IC Cost | Gross Sales | Prod Lbs | Meat Cost | Season Cost |
96443    2/4/2017  -123456    1000          2000      11000       30000
```

I've tried the following statement, but I am getting all four records summed for both Sums which is not the value I want returned:

```
SELECT
AF.[Product Number],
AF.[Week End Date],
AF.[Inv Change Cost],
AF.[Gross Sales Lbs],
AF.[Production Lbs],
SUM(MC.[Actual Usage Cost]) AS MeatCost,
SUM(SC.[Actual Usage Cost]) AS SeasonCost
FROM Table1 AF
JOIN Table2 MC ON MC.[Product Number] = AF.[Product Number] AND MC.[Week Ending Date] = AF.[Week End Date]
JOIN Table3 SC ON SC.[Product Number] = AF.[Product Number] AND SC.[Week Ending Date] = MC.[Week Ending Date]
WHERE
AF.[Product Number] = '96443' AND
AF.[Week End Date] = '2/4/2017' AND
MC.[Rout Line Name] = 'Total Cost' AND
SC.[Rout Line Name] = 'Total Cost'
GROUP BY
AF.[Product Number],
AF.[Week End Date],
AF.[Inv Change Cost],
AF.[Gross Sales Lbs],
AF.[Production Lbs];
```

Which returns a result of:

```
Prod # | WE Date | IC Cost | Gross Sales | Prod Lbs | Meat Cost | Season Cost |
96443    2/4/2017  -123456   1000          2000       22000       60000
```

Do I need to sum all of my fields to get the desired result?

UPDATE:

I've attempted this statement:

```
SELECT
AF.[Product Number],
AF.[Week End Date],
AF.[Inv Change Cost],
AF.[Gross Sales Lbs],
AF.[Production Lbs],
MC.MeatCost,
SC.SeasonCost
FROM Table1 AF
    JOIN(
        SELECT [Product Number], [Week Ending Date], SUM([Actual Usage Cost]) AS MeatCost
        FROM Table2
        GROUP BY [Product Number], [Week Ending Date]
        )MC ON
        AF.[Product Number] = MC.[Product Number] AND
        AF.[Week End Date] = MC.[Week Ending Date]
    JOIN(
        SELECT [Product Number], [Week Ending Date], SUM([Actual Usage Cost]) AS SeasonCost
        FROM Table3
        GROUP BY [Product Number], [Week Ending Date]
        )SC ON
        SC.[Product Number] = MC.[Product Number] AND
        SC.[Week Ending Date] = MC.[Week Ending Date]
WHERE
AF.[Product Number] = '96443' AND
AF.[Week End Date] = '2/4/2017';
```

However, I'm getting the same result as the previous attempt.

Comment: Do you have anymore fields? What is Season Cost?

Comment: I have quite a few more fields, but most of them are all unique to their respective tables

Comment: Your query works as expected, but need to know the difference between 96443 product numbers... Something in Table3.

Comment: It should be the same product number. Do I need to specify that for each table that the product number is X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this example and try something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), ProdNum INT, WeekEndDate DATETIME, InvChangeCost NUMERIC(18,2), GrossSales NUMERIC(18,2), ProductionLibs NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #Table1( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,InvChangeCost ,GrossSales ,ProductionLibs)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  -123456,   1000,           2000)

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), ProdNum INT, WeekEndDate DATETIME, MeatCost NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #Table2( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,MeatCost)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  5000)
INSERT INTO #Table2( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,MeatCost)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  6000)

CREATE TABLE #Table3 (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), ProdNum INT, WeekEndDate DATETIME, SeasonCost NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #Table3( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,SeasonCost)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  1000)
INSERT INTO #Table3( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,SeasonCost)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  2000)

SELECT t1.*
        , t2.MeatCost
        , t3.SeasonCost
FROM #Table1 t1
    JOIN (
            SELECT ProdNum, WeekEndDate, SUM(MeatCost) AS MeatCost
            FROM #Table2 
            GROUP BY ProdNum, WeekEndDate
         )t2 ON
        t1.ProdNum = t2.ProdNum AND
        t1.WeekEndDate = t2.WeekEndDate
    JOIN (
            SELECT ProdNum, WeekEndDate, SUM(SeasonCost) AS SeasonCost
            FROM #Table3 
            GROUP BY ProdNum, WeekEndDate
         )t3 ON
        t3.ProdNum = t2.ProdNum AND
        t3.WeekEndDate = t2.WeekEndDate


DROP TABLE #Table1  
DROP TABLE #Table2
DROP TABLE #Table3
```

Comment: This is very similar to a solution I was going to propose that used CTEs in place of the subqueries in the JOINs.

Comment: @digital.aaron Show us. I don't use many CTE's and would like to see.

Comment: It uses the same idea. Find the subtotals for Meat cost and Season cost, then join those into the final SELECT. I like CTEs because they tend to be easier to read.

Comment: This would work, except I'd have to insert the values from an already existing table on SQL Server..... is that practical?

Comment: No, we want you to replace the temptable with your physical tables.

Comment: I understand that much, however the ID would probably be a varchar(32)

Comment: Just take the SELECT query from the example above and replace #Table1, #Table2, and #Table3 with your physical tables relating to those. Leave the rest of the example out. Your data types are fine.

Comment: Just tried it... no dice. Still summing up four rows

Comment: How many records for Prod# 96443 and Week End Date 2/4/17 do you have in your Table1?

Comment: Wait! I left one minor WHERE in the two subqueries and it works! Thanks a bunch for both you and @digital.aaron 's help!

Answer (score 2):

I used Manderson's temp tables and rearranged the subqueries into CTEs.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), ProdNum INT, WeekEndDate DATETIME, InvChangeCost NUMERIC(18,2), GrossSales NUMERIC(18,2), ProductionLibs NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #Table1( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,InvChangeCost ,GrossSales ,ProductionLibs)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  -123456,   1000,           2000)

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), ProdNum INT, WeekEndDate DATETIME, MeatCost NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #Table2( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,MeatCost)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  5000)
INSERT INTO #Table2( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,MeatCost)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  6000)

CREATE TABLE #Table3 (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), ProdNum INT, WeekEndDate DATETIME, SeasonCost NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #Table3( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,SeasonCost)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  1000)
INSERT INTO #Table3( ProdNum ,WeekEndDate ,SeasonCost)
VALUES(96443,    '2/4/2017',  2000)

;WITH cteMeatCost
AS
(
    SELECT ProdNum, WeekEndDate, SUM(MeatCost) AS MeatCost
            FROM #Table2 
            GROUP BY ProdNum, WeekEndDate
)

,cteSeasonCost
AS
(
    SELECT ProdNum, WeekEndDate, SUM(SeasonCost) AS SeasonCost
            FROM #Table3 
            GROUP BY ProdNum, WeekEndDate
)

SELECT t1.*
        , t2.MeatCost
        , t3.SeasonCost
FROM #Table1 t1
    JOIN cteMeatCost t2 ON
        t1.ProdNum = t2.ProdNum AND
        t1.WeekEndDate = t2.WeekEndDate
    JOIN cteSeasonCost t3 ON
        t3.ProdNum = t2.ProdNum AND
        t3.WeekEndDate = t2.WeekEndDate


DROP TABLE #Table1  
DROP TABLE #Table2
DROP TABLE #Table3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
SELECT
AF.[Product Number],
MAX(AF.[Week End Date]),
MAX(AF.[Inv Change Cost]),
MAX(AF.[Gross Sales Lbs]),
MAX(AF.[Production Lbs]),
SUM(MC.[Actual Usage Cost]) AS MeatCost,
SUM(SC.[Actual Usage Cost]) AS SeasonCost
FROM Table1 AF
JOIN Table2 MC ON MC.[Product Number] = AF.[Product Number] AND MC.[Week Ending Date] = AF.[Week End Date]
JOIN Table3 SC ON SC.[Product Number] = AF.[Product Number] AND SC.[Week Ending Date] = MC.[Week Ending Date]
WHERE
AF.[Product Number] = '96443' AND
AF.[Week End Date] = '2/4/2017' AND
MC.[Rout Line Name] = 'Total Cost' AND
SC.[Rout Line Name] = 'Total Cost'
GROUP BY
AF.[Product Number]
```

Comment: No dice. It still duplicated the sum of MC and SC, and I may need to sum up the Gross Sales and Pounds as well.